# extract complete content of websites via feed in php

Tags: php, feed, simplepie

i want get complete content of a news or post of a website via feed. but we know that many websites only presents some part of news or post via their feed.
of course i know that exists a script called [`SimplePie`](http://simplepie.org/) that is developed for get content of websites via feed. but this script do not retrieve full content of a news.
of course i found a script called [`Full-Text Feeds`](http://fivefilters.org/content-only/) that do It. but it is no free . i want a free script.
Do you know a similar script or way to do my need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code behind Five Filters' content extraction is actually [open source](http://code.fivefilters.org/php-readability/), and is based on Readability's original Javascript (before they became a service).

You should be able to use it like this:

```
$page = file_get_contents($item_url);
$readability = new Readability($page);
if ($result = $readability->init()) {
    $content = $readability->getContent()->innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: @drtanz Fixed that up, looks like they restructured their site.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do here but this might help you:

```
$full_page_content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

Edit: Ok, if I understand you correctly you'll need to do something like this:

```
Get rss feed
Use SimplePie or something like it to go through each feed item
For each item in RSS feed
  Get the item's url
  Get the content from that URL
  Strip out the HTML/extract only the text you need
Combine all of these into a new RSS feed and send that to the user
```

Note: This isn't a simple thing to do. There is a reason that Full-Text RSS can charge for their product.

Comment: OP essentially wants a free version of the above linked Full-Text feeds.

Answer (score -2):

You could use http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/cookbook.shtml (free)

It retrieves RSS feeds. There are many many many PHP scripts that do that on the web... Google si your friend !! :)

Comment: Ahmad here is looking for a free script that takes the feed and then fetches the full content of the news item, instead of just the feed excerpt